Next.js 14, Tesseract.js Error: cannot find module .../.next/worker-script/node/index.js'
I am trying to extract text from the image with tesseract.js node module, i am working with nextjs 14. even though i have install the tesseract.js module i get error that module not find when i try to extract i get this error:
Error: Cannot find module '...(projectdirectory)/.next/worker-script/node/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:186:26)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:822:20)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}


it should look into the node modules not in .next
so for that i try to change the path of worker-sript in my file
const worker = await createWorker('eng',1,{workerPath: "./node_modules/tesseract.js/src/worker-script/node/index.js"});

but after changing the path there another error get thrown that is:
TypeError: fetch is not a function
i dont know why its happening... from my side everthing is fine, everthing works in my project execpt this.. function
i try to change the path of worker module here is the code :
import {createWorker} from 'tesseract.js';

export const imgToText = async () =>{
      //const converter = await createWorker('eng')
      const worker = await createWorker('eng',1,{workerPath: "./node_modules/tesseract.js/src/worker-script/node/index.js"});
      try {
            const img = "/fake.png"
            const text = await worker.recognize(img);
            console.log(text.data.text);
            return text.data.text;
      } catch (error) {
            console.log("image extraction error", error);
            throw error;
      } finally {
            await worker.terminate();
      }
}


i expect text from the image here.
but i got the fetch is not a function so i try to install the node-fetch module but it also didnt worked.
thank you!

I had the same issue and I stumbled across this post, followed the instructions from the first comment and it worked!

Try modifying your config to mark it as an external package. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverComponentsExternalPackages
This is necessary for many Node.js libraries. It changes the way the code is transpiled and packaged but I don’t know specifics.

https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/18qa0eo/deleted_by_user/

I encountered this error and found this post. but recent nextjs documentation removed the above link and found a github discussion with same issue.
    const nextConfig = {
       experimental: {
          serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['tesseract.js'],
          outputFileTracingIncludes: {
             '/api/**/*': ['./node_modules/**/*.wasm', './node_modules/**/*.proto']
          }
       }
    };

Adding this configs will solve this issue.

Github Discussion


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
